# Excel worksheet property view changes

Tags: excel, powershell, methods, properties, comobject

I have seen a property (or method) for excel .com objects that combined with .visible property shows changes to spreadsheet as they happen. But for the life of me I cannot find it now. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean set Excel to AutoCalculate ?

If so, that can be done like this:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
# open an Excel file because you can only set the '.Calculation' property when at least one workbook is opened
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open('X:\SomeFile.xlsx')

# set Autocalculation, see below 
$excel.Calculation = -4105  # turn on AutoCalculate
```

These are the accepted values for `.Calculation`, from [XlCalculation enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation)

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xlCalculationAutomatic | -4105 | Excel controls recalculation. |
| xlCalculationManual | -4135 | Calculation is done when the user requests it. |
| xlCalculationSemiautomatic | 2 | Excel controls recalculation but ignores changes in tables. |